# Input detection for a Group with overlapping transparent Images

Tags: libgdx

I use a Group to store some Images and draw them to a SpriteBatch. Now I want to detect which Image has been clicked. For this reason I add an InputListener to the Group to get an event on touch down. The incoming InputEvent got an method  (*getTarget*) that returns an reference to the clicked Actor.

If I click on a transparent area of an Actor I want to ignore the incoming event. And if there is an Actor behind it I want to use this instead. I thought about something like this:

```
    myGroup.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Actor targetActor = event.getTarget();
            // is the touched pixel transparent: return false
            // else: use targetActor to handle the event and return true
        };
    });
```

Is this the right way to do it? I thought returning false for the method *touchDown* would continue propagation for the event and let me also receive touchDown events for other Actors at the same position. But this seems to be a misunderstanding...

**UPDATE**

P.T.s answer solves the problem of getting the right Event. Now I have got the problem to detect if the hit pixel is transparent. It seems to me that I need the Image as a Pixmap to get access. But I do not know how to convert an Image to a Pixmap. I also wonder if this is a good solution in terms of performance and memory usage..

Comment: You don't go from Image to Pixmap. You go from Pixmap to Texture to Drawable to Image.

Comment: Did you try the solution which i provided?

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to override the [`Actor.hit()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#hit%28float,%20float,%20boolean%29) method. See the [scene2d Hit Detection wiki](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d#Hit_detection).

To do this, subclass `Image`, and put your `hit` specialization in there.  Something like:

```
public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
  Actor result = super.hit(x, y, touchable);
  if (result != null) { // x,y is within bounding box of this Actor
     // Test if actor is really hit (do nothing) or it was missed (set result = null)
  }
  return result;
}
```

I believe you cannot accomplish this within the `touchDown` listener because the Stage will have skipped the Actors "behind" this one (only "parent" actors will get the touchDown event if you return false here).